# How long can the server connection be persisted in db.js?

Tags: javascript, html, indexeddb, db.js

I'm looking at using the db.js wrapper for IndexedDB: https://github.com/aaronpowell/db.js

In the docs is says:

> A connection is intended to be persisted and you can perform multiple operations while it's kept open. Check out the /tests/public/specs folder for more examples

However the /tests/public/specs folder doesn't exist.

Should I open a new connection each time I have a group of operations to perform, or should I open it once and try to cache it for as long as possible in the client?

cheers,
Jordan.

Comment: Fixed the readme, it should have referred to `/tests/specs` folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connections are meant to be long-lived and reused.

Here's what [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#database-concept) has to say about connections:

> The act of opening a database creates a connection. There may be multiple connections to a given database at any given time. Each
> connection has a closePending flag which initially is set to false.
>
> When a connection is initially created it is in opened state. The connection can be closed through several means. If the connection is
> GCed or execution context where the connection is created is destroyed
> (for example due to the user navigating away from that page), the
> connection is closed. The connection can also be closed explicitly
> using the steps for closing a database connection. When the connection
> is closed the closePending flag is always set to true if it hasn't
> already been.
>
> The IDBDatabase interface represents a connection to a database.

In my experience, the only problem you'll run into with long-lived, re-used database connections is when you trigger a `versionchange` event by modifying schema:

> As long as a "versionchange" transaction is running, attempts to open
> more connections to the same database are delayed, and any attempts to
> use the same connection to start additional transactions will result
> in an exception being thrown.

Because of this, personally I architected my library not to reuse connections. But under most circumstances re-use should be fine.